# android:onClick of LinearLayout is not working correctly

Tags: android

I have a `LinearLayout` with two children, first is `ImageView` and second is `TextView`. `android:onClick` attribute is set for the `LinearLayout`. When I am clicking on `TextView` child the `onClick` method of `LinearLayout` is not called. But when I clicked on `ImageView`, `onClick` method is invoking. Below is my xml code:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="callOnClick">
        <ImageView
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_call" />

        <TextView
             android:id="@+id/tv_id"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:gravity="start"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             style="@style/text_style"
             android:layout_gravity="start"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"`, `android:duplicateParentState="true"`, `android:clickable="false"`, but nothis happened.

> A similar nested layout is working as expected, i.e. I can touch the parent Layout anywhere on it to call its `onClick` method. Below is the code for that Layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.ButtonBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/bar_id"
    style="@style/button_style"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="methodClicked"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_save" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="#eeeeee"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="ALL RECORDS"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_dimen" />
</android.support.v7.widget.ButtonBarLayout>
```

> Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, you set `duplicateParentState` and `clickable` on the TextView?

Comment: @Hod yes. .....